# gdb automatic-continue waits for ENTER?

Tags: gdb

According to [gdb docs](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Break-Commands.html), I can automatically continue after stopping on a breakpoint like this:

```
break 403
commands
cont
end
```

I'm trying to conditionally continue after a breakpoint like this:

```
set confirm off
set pagination off

define test
printf "%d\n", $x
set $x = $x + 1
if $x == 1
cont
end
end

break 403
commands
test
end
```

This *almost* works.

gdb indeed stops and checks for the condition (`$x == 1`). However it does not continue immediately when the condition is true.
**Instead it just shows the prompt**. If I click ENTER it either continues execution (when `$x == 1`), or remains in the prompt (if `$x != 1`).

Currently I just hit ENTER enough times until it does not continue execution any more.
But why does it wait for ENTER?

(This is not a matter of pagination/confirmation as I set them both to `off`)

---

#### Update1

Seems to be related to macro usage?
It does not happen if using `commands` directly.

---

#### Update 2

For clarity, here is a complete session that demonstrates the problem:

```
$ gdb a.out 
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 9.2-0ubuntu1~20.04) 9.2
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
Type "show copying" and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
    <http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.

For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from a.out...
(gdb) set confirm off
(gdb) set pagination off
(gdb) define test
Type commands for definition of "test".
End with a line saying just "end".
>p i
>if i < 3
 >cont
 >end
>end
(gdb) b 8
Breakpoint 1 at 0x115e: file test.c, line 8.
(gdb) commands
Type commands for breakpoint(s) 1, one per line.
End with a line saying just "end".
>test
>end
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/amir.gonnen/projects/test/gdb-cont/a.out 

Breakpoint 1, main () at test.c:8
8          printf("%d", i);
$1 = 0

Breakpoint 1, main () at test.c:8
8          printf("%d", i);
(gdb) echo Hey gdb why is the prompt?
Hey gdb why is the prompt?$2 = 1

Breakpoint 1, main () at test.c:8
8          printf("%d", i);
(gdb) echo Hey gdb you show the prompt but you still continue!
Hey gdb you show the prompt but you still continue!$3 = 2

Breakpoint 1, main () at test.c:8
8          printf("%d", i);
(gdb) echo again...
again...$4 = 3
(gdb) echo not continuing any more.
not continuing any more.(gdb) 
not continuing any more.(gdb) 
not continuing any more.(gdb)
```

Answer (score 0):

This appears to work fine for me using GDB-10.0 on x86_64.

Are you sure it doesn't work? One thing I noticed is that you print `$x` *before* incrementing and checking it, which makes it a bit confusing.

Here is my session:

```
# gdbinit
set confirm off
set pagination off

define test
  set $x = $x + 1
  printf "  x = %d\n", $x
  if $x == 1
    printf "  continuing\n"
    cont
  end
end

set var $x = -2
```

```
gdb -q ./a.out
(gdb) source gdbinit
(gdb) list
1       int main()
2       {
3         int k = 0;
4         for (int j = 1; j < 100; j++) {
5           k += 1;
6         }
7         return k;
8       }
(gdb) b 5
Breakpoint 1 at 0x1139: file t.c, line 5.
(gdb) commands
Type commands for breakpoint(s) 1, one per line.
End with a line saying just "end".
>test
>end
(gdb) run
Starting program: /tmp/a.out

Breakpoint 1, main () at t.c:5
5           k += 1;
  x = -1
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Breakpoint 1, main () at t.c:5
5           k += 1;
  x = 0
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Breakpoint 1, main () at t.c:5
5           k += 1;
  x = 1
  continuing                 <<<=== Note: no 'c' required this time.

Breakpoint 1, main () at t.c:5
5           k += 1;
(gdb)
```

Comment: Yes I'm sure - it doesn't work. I've updated the question with a simpler example that demonstrates the problem. gdb version is 9.2. Maybe a bug in that gdb version?